# Grid Independence of Series approximation

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab

I'm working on a project where I need to write out in MatLab an application of the Runge-Kutta formula to approximate the Bessel function. One part of the problem says

```
Try step size r=0.2 and then use step-size halving to evaluate whether the numerical
solution is grid independent.
```

What does the term "grid independent" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0):

*grid dependent* usually means: the finer/coarser is your grid the better/worst is the approximate of your solution.

So I can imagine that *grid independent* means that the "quality" (in the sense of precision) of the approximate solution do **not** depend on how fine is your grid (i.e. how small is the step size).